# How to add two values in datediff mysql from the same column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with
Columns:OrderID int PK

Department varchar(100)

OrderDate date

OrderQty int

OrderTotal int.

I want to add two orderdates
from orderid 1 and 5. I tried to make self join but it return 0.

```
select p.orderdate,datediff(p.orderdate,m.orderdate) as d
from orders as p inner join
orders as m on p.OrderID = m.OrderID where p.OrderID =1 and
m.OrderID =5
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: *on p.OrderID = m.OrderID where p.OrderID =1 and
m.OrderID =5* 1 != 5

Comment: How it can be possible? `p.OrderID = 1` and `m.OrderID = 5` its clear, but.... `p.OrderID = m.OrderID`? `1 = 5`?

Comment: it's a self join, but I solved the problem I deleted p.OrderID = m.OrderID and I got the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wont get period of dates with two orders, it can be done by serveral ways, for example:

1. First variant:

```sql
    select p.orderdate,
           datediff(p.orderdate,m.orderdate) as d
    from   orders as p, 
           orders as m 
    where  p.OrderID = 1 and
           m.OrderID = 5
```

2. Second variant:

```sql
    select p.orderdate,
           datediff(p.orderdate,(select m.orderdate from orders as m where m.OrderID = 5) as d
    from   orders as p 
    where  p.OrderID = 1
```

Comment: It worked but why in my exmple it return 0?

Comment: because of `p.OrderID = m.OrderID`, that means in your example `1=5`, that always will be `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.orderdate,datediff(p.orderdate,m.orderdate) as d
from orders as p,orders as m 
where p.OrderID =1 and m.OrderID =5
```

should give you the expected result